# Regex for minimum number of appearances of capturing group on a line

Tags: regex, grep

I have a text file where each line consists of a series of numbers separated by spaces followed by a word. The numbers consist of only the digits 1 through 6 and the digits within each number are ordered and unique. The word at the end of the file is not important.

For example:

```
2356 345 12345 4 4 1 6 gripped
12346 2 2346 123456 2356 56 245 12346 13456 12456 misidentifies
1256 345 24 12456 12356 123456 12356 356 1256 5 26 swine
```

would all be valid lines within my file.

I need to write a `grep` command which uses a regex to match all lines which contain at least 8 numbers which have a 1 or a 6. That means the line `346 1245 136 23456 5 1356 123456 5 123456 123456 octettes` is a match (346, 1245, 136, 23456, 1356, 123456, 123456, 123456 are 8 numbers) but the line `1 236 145 23 16 4 12356 4 3 packers` is not a match (1, 236, 145, 16, 12356 are only 5 numbers).

Note: the regex does not have to match the full line. grep returns all lines with a match present somewhere so the only important part is having the minimum 8 matches.

I have constructed this regex: `((?:(?:123456)|(?:1[2-5]*)|(?:[2-5]*6)) )`
It matches all of the numbers which match the condition and does not count 123456 twice. My issue is now with counting the number of occurrences. A {8,} would be sufficient if all of the numbers matches were one after another but sometimes there is one (or more) number in between the matches (e.g. 134 4 245 1245).

I have tried a lot of things including putting `[2-5]{0,5}`, `[2-5]*` or `.*` in the matching group to be repeated (with a {8,}) but nothing seemed to work. They are either not matching correctly or giving a catastrophic backtracking error.

I am pretty new to regex so I might have misunderstood how some things work. I know I need to modify my capturing group for my {8,} quantifier to work but I do not know how.

Regex101 link with more examples and my current (partial) solution [here](https://regex101.com/r/gWSI2X/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are single spaces only, you might use

```
^(?:(?:[2345]+ )*[2345]*[16][1-6]* ){7}(?:[2345]+ )*[2345]*[16]
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole

  - `(?:[2345]+ )*` Optionally match numbers without 1 or 6
  - `[2345]*[16][1-6]*`  Match a number with 1 or 6
- `){7}` Close the non capture group and repeat 7 times
- `(?:[2345]+ )*[2345]*[16]` The 8th match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aX8lU0/1)

Example using grep `-E` matching 1 or more spaces or tabs:

```
grep -E "^(([2345]+[[:blank:]]+)*[2345]*[16][1-6]*[[:blank:]]+){7}([2345]+[[:blank:]]+)*[2345]*[16]" file
```

Example using grep `-P` matching 1 or more horizontal whitespace characters:

```
grep -P "grep -P "^(?>(?:[2345]+\h+)*+[2345]*[16][1-6]*\h+){7}(?:[2345]+\h+)*+[2345]*[16]" file" file
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following regular expression with `grep`:

```
^[ 2-5]*(?:[16][1-6]*[ 2-5]*){8}
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/zsyCTJ/1)

---

Consider the following string.

```
"34 25 216 5 24   215 16 126 216 356 1 5 26 1 cats"
 0000000111111111112223334444455555667777788
```

The substring labelled below with `000000` (`"34 25 2"`) matches `^[ 2-5]*`. Each substring labelled below with a sequence of the same (positive) digit matches `(?:[16][1-6]*\b[ 2-5]*)`.

---

The regular expression has the following elements:

```
^          # match the beginning of the string       
[ 2-5]*    # match zero or more charactors in the character class
(?:        # begin a non-capture group
  [16]     # match a character in the character class
  [1-6]*   # match zero or more characters in the character class
  [ 2-5]*  # match zero or more characters in the character class
){8}       # end the non-capture group and execute it eight times
```

---

Note that

```
(?:[16][1-6]*[ 2-5]*){8}
```

could instead be used, but it is less efficient as it requires more backtracking.